# Is there a buildout recipe that uses pip but does not install virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, buildout, pip

I would like to use buildout rather than virtualenv.  This decision means that I don't want virtualenv to be snuck into my kit, so I am looking for either a way to tell gp.recipe.pip *not* to install the virtualenv meme virus, or, a way to install packages from git repos for use with django/djangorecipe.

Ideas?

Comment: Not an answer, just curious what's the aversion to virtualenv? My impression was that it's fairly common for buildout users to enclose their buildouts inside a virtualenv, for better isolation from system Python than that provided by buildout (could be wrong, I don't use buildout).

Comment: I don't want to be isolated from the system python.  That is the thing.  I just want my apps to look for certain modules ( the ones my apps are depending on ) in some location _first_ and then if they don't find them there ( meaning that in my opinion, I don't need a app specific version of this module, such as say, django, or mysql drivers, or PIL) then keep looking on the path.  In fact, that is the purpose of sys.path and $PYTHONPATH.  This methodology works fine for everything unix, last time I checked. So, _why_ virtualenv?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure,
You want to use [mr.developer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer) in your buildout.

Specifically, (taken from the mr.developer page), something like:

```
[buildout]
extensions = mr.developer
auto-checkout = my.package

[sources]
my.package = svn http://example.com/svn/my.package/trunk update=true
some.other.package = git git://example.com/git/some.other.package.git
```

That will get you the packages that you were after from git, installed as developed eggs into your buildout.

Comment: I completely prefer buildout to virtualenv.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @chiggsy buildout and virtualenv are different and work very well together. In fact the buildout doc even recommend to use them together. pip does some things that buidlout cannot ... so using them all together is the best combo imho: a buildout inside a virtualenv . Then as needed use additional recipes such as gp.recipe.pip, collective.recipe.pip, rjm.recipe.venv, buildout.dumprequirements, mr.scripty and mr.developer gets you a mucho better combo.